# Detect Button Signal on Microcontroller ATmega328P Using C Language

Tags: c, microcontroller, led

Microcontroller : ATmega328P

I encounter a problem with the following codes. It is used to control the LED light with a button connected to PB0.

There are 2 state :
 1. state_0 - All LEDs are OFF.
 2. state_1 - All LEDs are ON.

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0x00;    //set PINB as a input port for receiving PB0 signal
    DDRD = 0xFF;    //set PORTD as a output port for driving the LEDs
    unsigned char state_0 = 0x00;   //all LED bits are off
    unsigned char state_1 = 0xFF;   //all LED bits are on

    PORTD = state_0 //initialize the state  <----Still work here, Not work after this instruction.

    while(1)
    {   
        if(PINB0 == 0 && PORTD == state_0)      //when the button is not pressed and the LEDs are off
        {
            PORTD = state_0;                    //the LED states remain all off 
        }
        else if(PINB0 == 0 && PORTD == state_1) //when the button is not pressed and the LEDs are on
        {
            PORTD = state_1;                    //the LED states remain all on
        }
        else if(PINB0 == 1 && PORTD == state_0) //when the button is pressed and the LEDs are off
        {
            PORTD = state_1;                    //the LED states are turned to all on
        }
        else                                    //when the button is pressed and the LEDs are on
        {
            PORTD = state_0;                    //the LED states are turned to all off
        }
    }
}
```

---

After some testing, I find that the microcontoller cannot detect any signal from PB0. When I directly connect Vcc to PB0 or directly connect GND to PB0, I get the same result. When I press the button, nothing is changed.

```
while(1)
{
    if (PINB0 == 0)
        PORTD = 0x00;
    else
        PORTD = 0xFF;
}
```

---

Connection for the above codes :
[image] 
Not work
[image]

---

To test the button, I try the following. It is work so the botton work properly.
[image]

---

Do you know what is wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If even direct galvanic connection to +Vdd and ground doesn't work, then this seems like a hardware issue. There is, however, another error IIRC: reading from an output port doesn't do any good (i. e. it doesn't result in the actual state of the port). You would be better off keeping track of the port's state yourself (in a separate variable).

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that your program doesn't actually detect change of state - if `while` loop is operating fast enough (and probably is) even brief push to button will trigger both `if(PINB0 == 0 && PORTD == state_0)` and `else` part.

Consider adding some kind of checking state - like this:

```
int old_state = 0;

while(1) {   
    if (old_state != PINB0) {
        if(PINB0 == 0 && PORTD == state_0)      //when the button is not pressed and the LEDs are off
         {
            PORTD = state_0;                    //the LED states remain all off 
        }
        else if(PINB0 == 0 && PORTD == state_1) //when the button is not pressed and the LEDs are on
        {
            PORTD = state_1;                    //the LED states remain all on
        }
        else if(PINB0 == 1 && PORTD == state_0) //when the button is pressed and the LEDs are off
        {
            PORTD = state_1;                    //the LED states are turned to all on
        }
        else                                    //when the button is pressed and the LEDs are on
        {
            PORTD = state_0;                    //the LED states are turned to all off
        }
      }
      old_state = PINB0;
    }
```

(sorry about bad indentation, it's quite hard to get it right here)